# How to Include PyQt with Jython 2.5.2?

Tags: python, pyqt, jython

I am planning to use PyQt with Jython because my app is based on Java. I have installed Jython successfully. But i am lacking in including PyQt with Jython.

Any suggestions would be appreciative!

P.S: I am totally new to Python.

Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to create a GUI wrapper around an separate application written in a separate language or are you trying to add a GUI to an existing application?

Comment: @Kaleb Pederson: Not like that. I just wanted to use the offline browser api in Qt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi,
you cannot use PyQt with Jython.
PyQt are Qt bindings for 'standard' Python implementation (CPython).
If you want to use Qt in your Java app, 
then you can take a look at [Qt Jambi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qt_Jambi) (Qt bindings for Java, deprecated in 2009).

Comment: Keep in mind that Qt Jambi is no longer supported directly by Nokia.

Comment: +1 PyQt is compiled against CPython libraries while Jython is a pure Java implementation of the Python interpreter. Since Jython doesn't use the CPython libraries, you can't use PyQt.

Comment: @pedrotech: Actually i started with Qt jambi. I was having a very hard time with setting up jambi in my machine. Then i came to know about spynner, so i came to jython. Thanks for your response. Now, again i am going try jambi.

Comment: I stumbled across this Q&A, as I am looking for a way to use Qt with Java. My first thought was PyQt (as it seems to be the most stable/popular/widely supported Qt binding in third party language). But having realize that what I really wanted was a Qt binding for Java, it seems like Qt Jambi is the way to go. Will try using the 4.8.5 beta 4 though... thanks!